# kotlin double with 4 number after comma in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

The default of `Double` in android kotlin is `1121.57`. How to convert it to `1.121,5767` to make `4 number after comma`? even though behind the comma is `0` like this: `1.121,0000`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is String.format. Nothing kotlin specific needed there, look up java docs.

Comment: can you give me a link to the docs? Because I confused what query of googling for that

Comment: Or you can give me a sample code to convert it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
the specific thing you might be interested in is 
'#' - The result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form.
DecimalFormat might come in handy too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an extension function for `Double` and use a German format for the output, like this:

```
fun main() {
    val myDouble: Double = 1121.57
    val anotherDouble: Double = 100000.99
    println(myDouble.format(4))
    println(anotherDouble.format(4))
}

fun Double.format(digits:Int) = String.Companion.format(
                                    java.util.Locale.GERMAN,
                                    "%#,.${digits}f",
                                    this
                                )
```

It returns the following `String`

```
1.121,5700
100.000,9900
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

please pass your value to the following function and let me know if it works for you.

```
fun formattedNumber(number: Double): String{
    val formattedNumber = String.format("%.7f", number)
    val split = formattedNumber.split(".");
    val str = StringBuilder(split[1])
    str.insert(3, ',')
    return "${split[0]}.${str}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class. You can easily set the scale to 4 digits and it can be created with a Double.